# Working with floats in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: glsl, opengl-es2

Are there any reasons or situations one would use in their shader `float(1)` over just `1.0` ?

Comment: to be a rebel! I'm pretty sure that's not even valid it just compiles on reasonable drivers.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be valid? Section 5.4.1 of the GLSL spec says nothing about constants, any scalar value should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, any decent compiler will evaluate `float(1)` to `1.0` at compile time. The only thing you're doing by using `float(1)` is making your shader a little less readable.